# How do I get a variable from a graphQl query into a pseudo element in either inline styles or styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, pseudo-element, styled-components

I have a bit of a condrum I can't seem to solve I am querying colors from a graphQL database from DatoCMS and want to change the color of a Pseudo element in my Gatsby js app
I can do so just fine like this with a regular selector

```
<p style={{color: pricing.packageBorderColor.hex}} className="price-session">
   <span>${pricing.priceAmount}</span> | <span>{pricing.lengthOfSession}</span>
</p>
```

However I am not sure how to introduce sudo selector like `:after` into the mix.

```
const ListItem = styled.li`
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;
  &:before {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(renderToString(<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />))});
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -31px;
    color: {pricing.packageBorderColor.hex} // This is what I'd ideally like to do, but doesnt seem doable
  }
  span{
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    margin-top:3px;
  }
`
```

I have thought maybe styled components and This works, however I then Can't add my variables because styled components seems to live outside there scope before my loop and react component.

Updated Attempt

```
const CircleSave = styled.div`
  &:after{
    background: ({color}) => color
  }

`

<CircleSave color={pricing.packageBorderColor.hex} className="circle-save">
   <p>${pricing.packageSavings}</p>
   <p>savings</p>
 </CircleSave>
```

I get the following error in my rendered css

```
.chrVyZ:after {
    background: ({color}) => color;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [styled components passed props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) to pass props like this:

```
const ListItem = styled.li`
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;
  &:before {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(renderToString(<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />))});
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -31px;
    color: ${({ color }) => color}; // This is what I'd ideally like to do, but doesnt seem doable
  }
  span{
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    margin-top:3px;
  }
`
```

and then use it like normal component with a color prop:

```
<ListItem color={pricing.packageBorderColor.hex}/>
```

Comment: I tried your code, I must be doing something wrong, I updated my code above with my attempt, and the css error I got in inspect mode. Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add inline string template. It should be like this `color: ${({ color }) => color};`. I've updated my answer.